# Push specific amount of files into array

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of code that pushes files into an array that will be send with json. But i need only the first 9 files from the directory pushed into the array.

Also i need the same code that ignores the first 9 files in the folder and only pushes 10 and above in an array.

Cant seem to figure out how, this is my code:

```
$filenameArray = [];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))."/images/imagess/$id");

while($file = readdir($handle)){    
    if(strpos($file, ".jpg" || strpos($file, ".png")){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "images/imagess/$id/$file");
        }
     }
}

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
```

Comment: Do an increment count in the while loop, when it reaches 9 break,caveman programming style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use counter (in this example, variable `$i`), and also add missing right bracket:

```
$filenameArray = [];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))."/images/imagess/$id");
$i = 9;
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($i){

        if(strpos($file, ".jpg") || strpos($file, ".png")){
        //                    ^^^
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                array_push($filenameArray, "images/imagess/$id/$file");
            }
        }
        $i--;//decrement the counter until it reaches 0
    }
}

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
```

If you need 9 files that meets your criteria, place the decrement in the proper `if` condition statement.

To ignore first 9, just change it o:

```
$filenameArray = [];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))."/images/imagess/$id");
$i = 9;
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if(strpos($file, ".jpg") || strpos($file, ".png")){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            if($i > 0){
                $i--;
            }else{
                array_push($filenameArray, "images/imagess/$id/$file");
            }
        }
    } 

}

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for edit, but dont think the second code will work because it needs to ignore the first 9 files that meets the criteria, now it would start counting folders etc. too right?

Comment: OK, then use the now edited code - if it meets criteria,it either decrements the counter or pushes the file, depending on the current counter value.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a variable and add to it on each interation.

```
$filenameArray = [];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__))."/images/imagess/$id");
$i = 1;
while($file = readdir($handle)){    
    if(strpos($file, ".jpg" || strpos($file, ".png")){
        if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
            array_push($filenameArray, "images/imagess/$id/$file");

            if(++$i == 9) break;
        }
     }
}

echo json_encode($filenameArray);
```

Comment: thanks worked, do you also have an idea how to ignore the first 9 files and push 10 and above in the array?